# use of <jsp:useBean> tag

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

consider i have declared a class as:

```
public class Calcultor{

public int cube(int n){return n*n;}

}
```

now are both the below declarations same?

1. index.jsp:

   ```
   <jsp:useBean id=obj class="Calculator"/>
   <%
   int m=obj.cube(5);
   out.println("cube of 5 is "+m)
   %>
   ```
2. index.jsp:

   ```
   <%
   Calculator obj=new Calculator();
   int m=obj.cube(5);
   out.println("cube of 5 is "+m);
   %>
   ```

if both are same, what is the advantage?

Answer (score 3):

It's not the same. jsp:useBean will locate an instance of Calculator in some scope (request, session ...) that someone has created before (servlet, framework, controller etc.) while the scriptlet creates a new instance.

Check this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro11.html

btw the implementation of cube is wrong, it should be return n*n*n

Answer (score 0):

If we use usebean tag it will hide the "java coding" to get the feel of code like html  structure..it will give uniform look for the page code...

in the second one is in inside "jsp scriplet" which is used when we want to code a java multiple statements in jsp page(mostly avoided in mvc architecture to write biz logic and view together).... :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider rewording your answer to be more clear and to more directly answer the question.