# Instantiation: <jsp:useBean> vs. new keyword

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, scriptlet

Just hoping to clarify:

In a JSP page, would it be correct to say that `<jsp:useBean>` performs the same function as the `new` keyword used within a scriptlet?

I understand some of the benefits of standard actions, just making sure I'm solid on the fundamentals.

(Saw a similar question here: [use of <jsp:useBean> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006793/use-of-jspusebean-tag), but couldn't find a clear answer).

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite, `useBean` first *looks for* a bean with the given ID, but if it is not present in the scope defined, it will then be created.

From [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro11.html):

> The jsp:useBean element declares that the page will use a bean that is
>   stored within and accessible from the specified scope, which can be
>   application, session, request, or page. If no such bean exists, the
>   statement creates the bean and stores it as an attribute of the scope
>   object (see Using Scope Objects).

So you won't be guaranteed a new object if one already exists in your application.

Comment: Thanks - very clear. Am I correct that the bean instance can then be accessed as not only an attribute of whichever scope, but also as a local variable within `_jspService()`?

Comment: As far as I remember, they are available to the `_jspService()` method through the PageContext object, though not 100% on how they get parsed.